# Regular expression for matching SNMP traps

Tags: regex, perl, snmp, net-snmp

I have an snmptrapd daemon running in the background and logging all the traps to a file, and **I am trying to parse that log in a perl program**.

The SNMP v2c traps are being logged as follows:

```
SNMPv2[**]2013-11-4[**]13:16:49[**]UDP: [127.0.0.1]:57819->[127.0.0.1][**].1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1       .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 = INTEGER: 30 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.2 = STRING: lol
```

I have successfully parsed the OID, and the remote IP address using regular expressions, but I am unable to parse all the remaining trap values. Those are:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 = INTEGER: 30 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.2 = STRING: lol
```

The syntax seems easy: TRAP_STUFF = TYPE: VALUE repeated 0 or more times.

So the question is **which regular expression will allow me to grab all this information?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, for the left part of the log line, you could use `while` to parse out the information block by block with `regex`.

```
my $str = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 = INTEGER: 30 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.2 = STRING: lol";
while ($str =~ /([\.\d]+)\s=\s([^:]+):\s([\S]+)/g) {
    my ($trap_stuff, $type, $value) = ($1, $2, $3);
    print "trap_stuff: $trap_stuff\ntype: $type\nvalue: $value\n";
}
```

Output:

```
trap_stuff: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1
type: INTEGER
value: 30
trap_stuff: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.2
type: STRING
value: lol
```

Comment: I found a problem in this regular expression when the $str is like:


`SNMPv2[**]2013-11-7[**]16:38:40[**]UDP: [127.0.0.1]:53186->[127.0.0.1][**].1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (4567890) 12:41:18.90      .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.6306 .1.3.6.1.4.1.6306.2.1.1.0 = STRING: "05/08 13:26:35"`

The `STRING: "05/08 13:26:35"` part of it is not matched properly.

Comment: @user1816323 seems your pattern to match varies a lot. Do you have a list of information that would be parsed out? I've no idea about all the situations.

Comment: I fixed it by adding a white space in your regular expression behind the last \S. So it was `/([\.\d]+)\s=\s([^:]+):\s([\S ]+)/g`